Getting wrong Output for Second Dominant Eigen Value using Power Method Technique
As i am trying to write PCA from scratch, using the Power Method Technique to calculate the Eigen Values, only the first one is correct and rest other are incorrect . What am I doing Wrong ?
Using numpy , eigen values for covariance matrix are coming as [9.49506917 8.11919641 5.27687829]
whereas mine are coming as [9.495069168715409, 485.7201377095837, 25631.534012572032]. I am sharing my code structure too.
def normalize_data(train_x, test_x=None):
    scaler = StandardScaler()

    train_normalized = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(train_x), columns=train_x.columns)
    if test_x is not None:
        test_normalized = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(test_x), columns=test_x.columns)
    else:
        test_normalized = None

    return train_normalized, test_normalized

def extract_PCA(X, n_components=3):
    n = X.shape[0]
    cov_matrix = (X.T @ X) / (n-1)    
        
    eigen_vectors = []
    eigen_values = []
        
    for _ in range(n_components):
        # Find dominant eigen value and its corresponding eigen vector
        eigen_value, eigen_vector = using_power_method_find_dominant_eigen_value(cov_matrix)
# eigen_vectors.append(eigen_vector)
        eigen_values.append(eigen_value)
        
        eigen_vector = eigen_vector.reshape(256, 1)

        cov_matrix = cov_matrix - ( eigen_value * (eigen_vector @ eigen_vector.T) ) 
    
    
def using_power_method_find_dominant_eigen_value(mat_A, tolrence = 1e-10):
    n = mat_A.shape[0]
    x = np.ones(n)
    
    prev_value = 0
    prev_eigen_vector = x

    # while True:
    for _ in range(1000):
        x = np.dot(mat_A, x)
        eigen_value, x = vector_norm(x)
        print(eigen_value, np.linalg.norm(prev_eigen_vector - x, 2))
                
        if ( abs(eigen_value - prev_value) < tolrence ) and ( np.linalg.norm(prev_eigen_vector - x, 2) < tolrence):
            break
            
        prev_value = eigen_value
        prev_eigen_vector = x
        
    return eigen_value, x

def vector_norm(v):
    norm_coeff = max(v)
    
    # Step 2: Normalize the vector
    normalized_v = [vi / norm_coeff for vi in v]
    
    return norm_coeff, np.array(normalized_v)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    train_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
    test_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
    
    X_train, y_train = train_df.drop(columns= ['y'], axis=1), train_df['y']
    X_test, y_test = test_df.drop(columns = ['y'], axis=1), test_df['y']
    
    X_train, X_test = normalize_data(X_train, X_test)
    
    extract_PCA(X_train)
    `


To debug problems like this, start with a small problem for which you know the exact solution. Look at the results for a 2 by 2 matrix, start with ((1, 0), (0, 1)), then try other diagonal values, then try general 2 by 2. If that works then go on to 3 by 3 and so on. At some point the results will diverge from what you know ahead of time, and there you can start investigating. This applies to every kind of numerical calculation.

The part
cov_matrix = cov_matrix - ( eigen_value * (eigen_vector @ eigen_vector.T) ) 
of the PCA seems wrong. You seem to be subtracting the principle component from the covariance matrix directly. rather than subtracting it from X and recalculating the covariance matrix.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Further_components
